# PHP MySQL combine multiple fetchcolumn into a single query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've currently got a table with users and variable user status (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc). I am currently calculating the number of users in each status separately

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE status = 1";
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$users1 = $result->fetchColumn();

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE status = 2";
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$users2 = $result->fetchColumn();

etc
```

I could get a fetch, then loop through all the results and add each status but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it with a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group by and get the list with the count

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*)  as my_count FROM users group by status;
```

NB with  this you can't use fetchColumn  .. but fetchRow .and access by key

Comment: I'll still have to loop through the results to get the $users1/2/3 etc right?

Comment: yes .. correct you must loop over the result fof get each row and avcces by key 'status',,,and ''my_count'  to the values of each row ....(but you have select row for each status ...not for each $user)  ..

Answer (score 1):

you jsut need to add status as group by

```
SELECT COUNT(*),status FROM users group by status
```